tengo este error para generar reportes en PDF con fpdf181
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$this" in C:\xampp\htdocs\mi_tienda2\reportes\Factura.php on line 146
// Company
function addSociete( $nom, $adresse, $logo, $ext_logo  )
{
    $x1 = 30;
    $y1 = 4;
    //Positionnement en bas
    //$this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , $ext_logo);
    $this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , 0 , $ext_logo)
    /*Linea 146*/$this->SetXY( $x1, $y1 );
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    $length = $this->GetStringWidth( $nom );
    $this->Cell( $length, 2, $nom);
    $this->SetXY( $x1, $y1 + 4 );
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $length = $this->GetStringWidth( $adresse );
    //Coordonnées de la société
    $lignes = $this->sizeOfText( $adresse, $length) ;
    $this->MultiCell($length, 4, $adresse);
}


si la funcion no esta dentro de una clase ... $this no existe...

En ningún momento llega $this a la función

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. La pregunta carece de una explicación de la situación, solo tiras un mensaje de error y ¿un fragmento? de código, sin indicar de qué es parte o cómo está la situación. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve].

Por favor, lee [ask]. Ya en tu pregunta anterior se realizó una edición al título de tu pregunta describiendo brevemente el problema que estás teniendo. Además: provee siempre contexto, no copipegues solamente el código y el mensaje de error. Por otra parte, ya te han dado indicios de dónde está el problema. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

no sé si ya lo resolviste, a mi me salió un error mu parecido y era que me faltaba colocar el signo punto y coma al final.
$this->Image($logo, 5 , 3 , 25 , 0 , $ext_logo);

Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
